# EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Patient" was found

Tags: git, merge, nestjs, entity, typeorm

I'm getting this error while running nestJS application

```
[Nest] 12125  - 05/30/2023, 1:43:35 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "Patient" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Patient" was found.
    at DataSource.getMetadata (/Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:444:30)
    at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/src/repository/Repository.ts:53:40)
    at Repository.save (/Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/src/repository/Repository.ts:206:18)
    at HiuConsentService.patientsFind (/Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/src/hiu-consent/hiu-consent.service.ts:913:38)
    at HiuConsentController.patientsFind (/Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/src/hiu-consent/hiu-consent.controller.ts:129:49)
    at /Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /Users/rajveersingh/Desktop/parchaa/HIP/parchaa-hip/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

below is my hiu-consent.module.ts code

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'; 
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { RefreshTokenModule } from 'src/refresh-token/refresh-token.module';
import { HiuConsentController } from './hiu-consent.controller';
import { HiuConsentService } from './hiu-consent.service';
import { ConsentRequest } from './entities/consentRequest.entity';
import { ConsentsOnFetch } from './entities/cosentOnFetch.entity';
import { FideliusService } from 'src/fidelius/fidelius.service';
import { CmRequest } from './entities/cmRequest.entity';
import { Patient } from './entities/patient.entity';
import { DecryptedData } from './entities/data.entity';
import { HiuNotify } from './entities/hiuNotify.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    RefreshTokenModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          envFilePath: ".env",
        }),
      ],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: +configService.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
        synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('DB_SYNC'),
        entities: [ ConsentRequest, ConsentsOnFetch, CmRequest,Patient,DecryptedData, HiuNotify ]
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ConsentRequest, ConsentsOnFetch, CmRequest, Patient, DecryptedData, HiuNotify]),
  ],
  controllers: [HiuConsentController],
  providers: [HiuConsentService, FideliusService]
})
export class HiuConsentModule {}
```

here is my Patient entity

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Patient {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ default: 'abc'})
    patientId: string;

    @Column({ default: 'abc'})
    patientName: string;
}
```

Below is my file structure given
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9YVT.png)

please help me resolve this error

I had tried some ways like using entity.js from dist etc. but i don't know why this is not working. one other thing to note that i had 2 branches and i had merged them and two independent branches were working fine alone but when i merged code of branch B to branch A then code of branch B is giving this error, is it due to package-lock.json file?

Comment: Please don't send links to images of text. Please add the text as part of you question text instead.

Comment: Why tags [git] and [merge]? Please don't spam unrelated tags.